# Перенос скрипта python на ПК на котором нет возможности установить python

Tags: python

у меня есть скрипт написанный на python, его нужно перенести на ПК у которого нет доступа к интернету и не установлен python, к тому же на этот ПК нельзя устанавливать python.
Насколько  понял (после долгих поисков), это реализуемо, если как то создать виртуальное окружение, туда же добавить необходимые библиотеки, а в самом скрипте указать путь до папки с библиотеками.
Но информация настолько разрознена (и я в самом начале изучения python и всего что с этим связано), что связать это воедино и реализовать у меня не получается.
Буду благодарен за помощь.
Повторю суть вопроса: **запустить скрипт python на ПК на котором нет python, нет доступа к интернет  и нельзя устанавливать python.**

Comment: логичным было бы в список требований добавить ключевое: «и компьютера тоже нет».

Comment: Для создания виртуального окружения нужен установленный python, так что неправильно поняли. Возможно, вам нужен Pyinstaller

Comment: зачем это все вам нужно? возможно есть другое решение вашей проблемы?

Comment: Windows? Почему нельзя устанавливать python? Если нет админских прав, то это не проблема. Дистрибютив позволяет устанавливать и без них, если правильно выбрать настройки.

Comment: А ещё есть такой портативный вариант http://winpython.github.io/

Comment: @andreymal спасибо.
Дело в том, что я работаю на удаленном ПК и что бы установить python или библиотеки нужно обращаться к администратору, а этого не хочется делать. Тогда можно и вопрос задать по другому:
- Питон на ПК установлен но не хватает зависимости 'openpyxl' для 'pandas', т.е. pandas есть, но он не открывает файлы XLSX, требует  openpyxl. 
Можно как то добавить эту библиотеку 'openpyxl', что бы скрипт отрабатывал нормально?
Пробывал: `pip download openpyxl --dest Downloads\folderpyautogui` и потом в скрипте:
import sys
sys.path.append('Downloads\folderpyautogui') - не работает

Comment: @Alpensin "очкую я что то" не понятно что в итоге там работать будет, в плане безопасности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял питон всё же установлен. Если нет, его можно установить стандартным установщиком без админских прав. Просто надо выбрать установку для текущего юзера и не добавлять в переменные окружения. Или скачать отсюда портативную версию http://winpython.github.io/
По поводу установки библиотек я действовал следующим образом.

- Имел аналогичный питон на машине с интернетом с теми же библиотеками.
- Когда надо было что-то добавить выполнял на этой машине `python -m pip download [options] <local project path>`. [Детали команды](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/). Таким образом качал нужную библиотеку и все зависимости.
- Дальше копировал эти файлы на удалённый комп. А там `py -m pip install --no-index --find-links=file:///local/dir/ SomeProject` или `py -m pip install ./downloads/SomeProject-1.0.4.tar.gz` [Примеры](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-local-archives)